# How can I protect against an Object not being in a scene when FindingObject

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I currently have two scenes.  The first contains a "PowerUp" object.  So the script:

```
myPowerUp = GameObject.FindObjectWithTag("Fuel").GetComponent<AddFuel>();
```

finds the object.

I'm struggling to see how I can encapsulate this so that when in the second scene, I don't get an error thrown because the object WithTag("Fuel") Doesn't exist?

If I use a bool like this:

```
 if (!PowerUpExists){ 
    Return;
 } else {
 myPowerUp = GameObject.FindObjectWithTag("Fuel").GetComponent<AddFuel>() 
 }
```

Would something like that work?  I can't see how that logic would, because how can I check if something exists, without checking if something exists, if you catch my meaning?

Please help, I am quite new to this, learning, but by no means well progressed.

Answer (score 1):

Simply check if the gameObject exists:

```
GameObject powerUpGo = GameObject.FindObjectWithTag("Fuel");
if( powerUpGo != null )
{
    myPowerUp = powerUpGo .GetComponent<AddFuel>() ;
}
```

Then, when add a condition before using `myPowerUp`:

```
if( myPowerUp != null )
{
    // Do something with myPowerUp
}
```

---

Otherwise, I simply advise you to have a direct serialized reference of your object in the inspector so you can simply have a null check when your power up is needed (and you won't need to call `Find` anymore)

```
[SerializeField]
private AddFuel myPowerUp ; // Drag & drop the object in the inspector

// ...

if( myPowerUp != null )
{
    // Do something with myPowerUp
}
```

---

Last possibility I can think about, but requiring much more "manual" work, add a boolean you will check in the inspector according to the scene you are currently in.

```
[SerializeField]
private bool powerUpExists; // Check / uncheck it in the inspector according to the scene you are working in

// ...

if (!powerUpExists)
{ 
    return;
}
else
{
    myPowerUp = GameObject.FindObjectWithTag("Fuel").GetComponent<AddFuel>() 
}
```

Comment: You could do the scene check in code too, but you will have to hardcode it. Something like `if(SceneManager.GetActiveScene().buildIndex == X) powerUpExists = true`

Comment: Right, but I personnaly tend to minimize the work done in code. Digging into the code is often less pleasant than a simple check / drag & drop in the editor.
I am not a big fan of all the `FindXXX` methods, and I prefere the 2nd solution I've proposed.

Comment: Thanks, I think the Serialized bool for the inspector is the cleanest option, although that provide a small degree of risk, i.e. forgetting to set it when a new scene is created.  I'll try both later and see how I get on.  Thanks for the answers!!